# Find the limit of $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^\frac{3}{2}y}{x^3+y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find the limit of 
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^\frac{3}{2}y}{x^3+y^2}$$

If we set $x$ or $y$ equal to zero, we get $0$. But I'm not sure how else to prove this. Should I have $x=y$ or $y=mx$?

Comment: if you set $y=0$ it "blows up"

Comment: If $y=x^{3/2},$ you get $2.$

Comment: Try $y=x^{3/4}$  the limite is not zero

Comment: Converting to polar is a tried and true method to solve these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{2x^\frac{3}{2}}{x^3+y^2}$$

Try $y=x^{3/4}$ 
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2}{x^{3/2}+1}=2 \ne 0$$

Answer (score 1):

In these types of exercises, you might consider two cases:
1. The limit exists (which very often turns out to be quite challenging);
2. Prove that the limit does not exist. This is done choosing different approaches to the graph (as mentioned in the comment section). 
So in this case you have successfully concluded that for the approach $y = x$ the limit is $0$. 
Now try to find another relation: for example $y = x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ or $y = x^{\frac{3}{4}}$ as previously mentioned. The limit is not zero. This is enough to conclude that the limit does NOT exist.